# Bivectors generated by a set of five vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem that I haven't been able to solve:

Consider a set of ten bivectors $B_k\in\bigwedge^2\mathbb{R}^{4}$, $k=1,\dots,10$ such that each group of six of such bivectors is linearly independent. Suppose that we have five basis $\{e_{1}(k),\dots,e_4(k)\}:=\tau_{k}$, $k=1,\dots,5$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$. These basis have the following two properties;

a) Given a set of six $\{B_{j}\}_{j=1}^{6}$, there is a basis $\tau_{i}=\{e_{1}(i),\dots,e_4(i)\}$ such that each of the $B_{j}$ of such set is of the form $B_{j}=e_{n}(i)\wedge e_{m}(i)$ for some $e_{n}(i),e_{m}(i)\in\tau_{i}$.

b) Given two of such basis $\tau_{i}$, $\tau_{j}$, there are vectors $e_{a}(k), e_{b}(k), e_{c}(k)\in\tau_{k}$ and $e_{f}(l), e_{g}(l), e_{h}(l)\in\tau_{l}$ such that
$$e_{a}(k)\wedge e_{b}(k)=e_{f}(l)\wedge e_{g}(l)$$
$$e_{a}(k)\wedge e_{d}(k)=e_{f}(l)\wedge e_{h}(l)$$
$$e_{b}(k)\wedge e_{d}(k)=e_{g}(l)\wedge e_{h}(l)$$

I need to prove that there exist five vectors $v_{1},\dots,v_{5}\in\mathbb{R}^{4}$ such that every set of four of such vectors is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ whose elements generate, through the wedge product, six of the $B_{k}$, that is, every six $B_{k}$ are the wedge product of four of he $v_{l}$.

I have proved that a relation like $e_{a}(k)\wedge e_{b}(k)=e_{f}(l)\wedge e_{g}(l)$ implies that $span(e_{a}(k),e_{b}(k))=span(e_{f}(l),e_{g}(l))$, and I have tried to use this to prove that, of the five basis given, every two of such basis share three vectors, however I have not been able to do it. I have spent many time thinking about this problem, but I couldn't find a solution. Does anybody have an idea or suggestion.? This is important for me.